# Reducing the Matrix to Reduced Row Echelon Form

Tags: linear-algebra

> Reduce the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&-6\\4&-1&-15\\-2&2&12\end{bmatrix}$ to reduced row-echelon form

How is my answer incorrect?

I performed the row operations:

1) $R_2 = 4R_1 - R_2$

2) $R_3 = 2R_1 + R_3$

3) $R_2 = R_2 / -3$;

4) $R_3 = R_3/18$

5) $R_2 = R_2 + 7R_3$

6) $R_1 = R_1 + -6R_3$

7) $R_1 = R_1 + R_2$

Which gives me the RREF of the matrix

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

So how in the world is my solution incorrect?

Comment: According to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant+of+%7B%7B1,-1,-6%7D,%7B4,-1,-15%7D,%7B-2,2,12%7D%7D), this has a zero determinant, so the RREF can not be the identity matrix. I don't know exactly where you went wrong, though.

Comment: $-2R_1=R_3$ so there's no way this reduces to the identity.

Comment: I don't either...

Comment: @Shammy After step 2, you should get that the third row is completely zero.

Comment: $R_3 = -2 R_1$.  After step 2, Row 3 should be a zero vector.  Any steps involving row 3 that follow must be incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Step 1:

$$\left[\begin{matrix}1 & -1 & -6 \\
0 & -3 & -9 \\
-2 & 2 & 12\end{matrix}\right]$$

After Step 2:

$$\left[\begin{matrix}1 & -1 & -6 \\
0 & -3 & -9 \\
0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right]$$

After Step 3:

$$\left[\begin{matrix}1 & -1 & -6 \\
0 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right]$$

All of the steps with $R_3$ are unnecessary since $R_3$ is all zeroes. Skip to Step 7:

$$\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & -3 \\
0 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right]$$

Comment: -9 in first step?? what??????? how????????

Comment: @Shammy $$4\cdot -6-(-15)=-24+15=-9$$

Comment: I'm an idiot. On my paper I had a positive 6 in the third column when I wrote it down instead of a -6 -_-. I hate matrices

Comment: That's why I like to use Wolfram Alpha to check my work. For example, [here's Wolfram Alpha's answer to the RREF of this matrix](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=rref+of+%7B%7B1,-1,-6%7D,%7B4,-1,-15%7D,%7B-2,2,12%7D%7D).

Comment: I finally got it. Thank you @noble you truly are, Noble